# how do i create my array dynamically where values fetching from json in ios

Tags: ios, arrays

```
-(IBAction)DropDownPressed:(id)sender {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:NULL];
         NSArray * array = [greeting objectForKey:@"id"];

         NSLog(@ "%@",array);
         ibtn=0;
         [Dropobj fadeOut];
         [self showPopUpWithTitle:@"Select Country" withOption:arryList xy:CGPointMake(16, 58) size:CGSizeMake(287, 330) isMultiple:NO];

     }
 }
 ];
```

}

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      arryList=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"india",@"pakistan",nil ];
} 


 @interface ViewController : UIViewController<kDropDownListViewDelegate>{
 NSArray *arryList;
 int ibtn;
}
```

this is my interface file

i wish to create a arraylist like arryList in the viewdidload method..i fetch the json values from restapi call and convert those into arrays...those values i get from the restapi call have to be loaded dynamically...how to do it....please suggest me ideas....

Comment: If `arryList` is a property of your class - change `NSArray * array = [greeting objectForKey:@"id"];` to `self.arryList = [greeting objectForKey:@"id"];`

Comment: your coding is fine what the result u need

Comment: yeah bro i clerify you....i statically put values for arryList on viewdidload......now i am fetching values from restapicall ...convert those into arrays finally...NSArray * array = [greeting objectForKey:@"id"]; how do i load these values dynamically ....

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following way.

```
@interface MasterViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *arryList;

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize arryList;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   int totalData = 10;
   arryList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:totalData];
   for (int i=0; i<totalData; i++) {
      [arryList addObject:@""];
   }

}

-(IBAction)DropDownPressed:(id)sender{
UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
NSLog(@"tag:%d",button.tag);
id currentValue = [arryList objectAtIndex:button.tag];
if ([currentValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [(NSString*)currentValue isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    [self getURLResponse:&dataDictionary];
    NSString *myID = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *content = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"content"];
    [arryList replaceObjectAtIndex:button.tag withObject:myID];
    NSLog(@"arryList:%@",arryList);
}else{
 NSLog(@"already downloaded");
}

}


-(void)getURLResponse:(NSDictionary**)dataDictionary{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:
                    request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:nil];

//             ibtn=0;
//             [Dropobj fadeOut];
//             [self showPopUpWithTitle:@"Select Country" withOption:arryList xy:CGPointMake(16, 58) size:CGSizeMake(287, 330) isMultiple:NO];
*dataDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:greeting copyItems:YES];
}
```

Comment: it is difficult understand what you want if you add an screen shot in "i.imgur.com"

Comment: yeah @jamil65able  i wish to clarify you...in that screen shot....when i click button it displays the arryList values england,australia....similarly i wish to show my dynamic values....but if i put your method...for every time i click the button the values and rows gets increased overtime...

Comment: you should check if the data already contain, then you will not add otherwise add

Comment: http://imgur.com/pd2dECJ  on first time click the button dropdown doesn't show any value.    when i click another button select values in the dropdown then i click the first dropdown...it shows value...what might be the error..http://imgur.com/OMQyqW6 look at this screen shot

Comment: in the code there is a completion block "completionHandler:^{}"

that means, after click on the button , you will not get value until it finish download. So, emidiately, you will not get updated value,  so reload   table end of the  "completionHandler:^{
.....

[YourTableView reloadData]
}"

Comment: you are most welcome. if you  accept this answer (if acceptable), it will be helpful for others to find the correct answer.

Comment: NSString *data1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",content];
             NSLog(@ "%@",data1);
             
             
             //to check data1 is having value or not....
             if ( ![data1 isEqualToString:@"" ]  )
             {
                
                 NSLog(@ "%@",data1);
             }
             else
             {
                 
                 [arryList addObject:data1];
                 NSLog(@ "arryList:%@",arryList);
             }
instead of NSLog(@ "%@",data1); how to show my arryList what is the correct statement for this...please..

Comment: do you get different tag of DropDownPressed:(id)sender for each tap

Comment: yeah jamie65able it's ok.. iam asking mutable array can be edit...but it is not possible to show the data without edit....i am checking data1 having values or not if it having values...then show the arryList how can i done it...whether it is not possible at all.

Comment: on clicking the button it throws the error ...[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000001663

Comment: beacuse you from reset api you get 'id as nsnumber'

Comment: id currentValue = [arryList objectAtIndex:button.tag];
if ([currentValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [(NSString*)currentValue isEqualToString:@""]) {//inner code}//you should check by this way

Comment: [arryList replaceObjectAtIndex:button.tag withObject:myID]; instead of myid if i give content....it produces the correct output...what i have to check...if i get number like values....

Comment: [arryList replaceObjectAtIndex:button.tag withObject:content];screen shot like this  http://imgur.com/XiVDasR   if i need number values like this means where i have to check condition ...what i have to do...and init with capacity can be dynamic....in that screen shot one empty row has been displayed...it could be avoided?..means how.. finally,thanks a lot for spending this much time for this ......

Comment: provide some code where you write you condition and initialize arrayList

Comment: i am asking we are iniatialize  initwithcapacity totaldata....where totaldata=10 ; instead of that we will declare initwithcapacity as arrylistcount.. int totaldata =[arrylist count]; whether it is correct...

Comment: how many "DropDownPressed" you have? that will be the total data 'totalData'

Comment: if i set int totaldata=2  then i pressed the button first time it shows the screen shot  http://imgur.com/XiVDasR  now i am asking...arryList having only one value......that should be only listed in the dropdown no extra empty tableviews or rows won't display for that.....we can assign dynamically init with capacity....or do some changes? no issue in repeatedly pressing the dropdown button...

Comment: I can see only  "select,hello world,hello world" but i see you have 3 buttons and 3 labels. Do you want when you pressed a button data come from  rest-api will fill the that label?

Comment: i am saying that blue coloured dropdown design.....helloworld then one more empty row or table row is displaying...that is because of int totaldata=2 where arryList having value helloworld only...we are hardcoding initwithcapacity as 2....so it looping and produces..extra one row in dropdown design.....how to avoid this.. or how we can load the data dynamically by values in the arrylist..

Comment: then you should simply add data (i.e. [arrayList addObject:'content']) and sort them to show or use array of dictionary data. additionally, you cant [arrayList insertObject: atIndex:x] if your array does not contain data of that index 'x', it will cause crash.

Comment: how do i initiate your method.. add data and sort them or array of dictionary...from the api response i have to convert the response to array..

Comment: in your 'response dictionary' the 'content' always show 'hello wold' and the 'id' changes always. so it not possible detect which data has already downloaded. so, first you should get unique data from server. for a little bit i am updating how to call

Comment: NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    [self getURLResponse:&dic];
    NSLog(@"dic:%@",dic);

Comment: that id autochanging values not an issue i wish to add some other url provides standard values....now my doubt is we already calling the dictionary... NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    [self getURLResponse:&dataDictionary];   like this...

Comment: NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
         NSLog(@ "greeting:%@",greeting);
         //NSString *myID = [greeting objectForKey:@"id"];
         NSString *content = [greeting objectForKey:@"content"];
         
         NSString *data1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",content];
         
         if ([data1 isEqualToString:@"" ] )
         { NSLog(@ "%@",data1); }
         else
           
         {
             [arryList addObject:data1];
             
             NSLog(@ "arryList:%@",arryList);
         } now i go with this

Comment: ////---------------------------- Removing White space for Array ----------------------------////  for (int i = 0 ; i < arryList.count; i++) {  NSString *str = [arryList objectAtIndex:i];  if ([str isEqualToString:@""]) {  [arryList removeObjectAtIndex:i]; } }   ////---------------------------- Printing Array ----------------------------////  NSLog(@"arryList:%@",arryList);   }  if i put this....it removes the empty rows..for only int totaldata=2 if i give int totaldata=3 or 4...something like that...again it produces empty white spaces...how could i avoid this...help me on this @jamil65able